# How do I return a reference to an interface from a WCF contract?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service.  I can return a concrete class without a problem, but returning a reference to an interface causes the following issue.

CommunicationException occurred
"The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.2030000'."

This occurs when I try to get an instance of a class from a WCF service:

```
//create the connection
ChannelFactory<IService> _ChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(_EndpointName);
IService _ServiceProxy = _ChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

//communication exception thrown here
ITestInterface okcomputer = _ServiceProxy.GetTest();
```

IService and ITestInterface have all the normal OperationContract attributes and such.  The Service has the attribute: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

other than that, the classes and interfaces are nothing special.

I feel like there is some special trick to returning a class interface from a WCF interface, otherwise I wouldn't be having this problem.. What's the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return an interface, ever. How would it be serialized?

Interfaces are about behavior. Behavior is not serialized, only data.

Comment: Can too! What's the XML Schema definition of your interface? What's the WSDL look like? It's web services, so is this interface a service contract? If so, it has operations. How do you serialize an operation?

Comment: during development time, I designed this with the option of swapping out stubbed out versions for debugging.  Can I achieve the same functionality if I replace the references to interfaces with references to abstract base classes or base class and subclass combinations?

Comment: You need a concrete class. It's the schema of the concrete class that will be seen by the clients.

Comment: True Service-oriented programming is quite a different beast from OO-programming! You need to "unlearn" certain principles again.....

Comment: damn, I put so much effort into learning OO best practices too.  This really screws me up.

Comment: Who ever told you that web services were OO? And I'd just as well break it to you now, to prevent future disappointment: XML is not OO, either.