# Interface Parameter / Return Type in a WCF Service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service and an MVC client that has a service reference to the aformentioned. I am trying to use marker interfaces as return types and parameters but I'm having trouble generating the service reference to reflect this.

I'm currently getting a return type / parameter type of "object" in my service reference so my question is how would I go about resolving this as the actual function in my service takes and returns an interface of `IWorkRequest` and `IWorkResponse` respectively.

My service contract looks like the following:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IWorkResponse DoWork(IWorkRequest request);
}
```

My service-side interfaces look like the following:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(WorkRequestA))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(WorkRequestB))]
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IWorkRequest 
{

}
```

I have a similar one for IWorkResponse following the same pattern. When I build the project and update the service reference to it then the service reference looks like:

```
public object DoWork(object request) {
    return base.Channel.DoWork(request);
}
```

I also have no reference to the interfaces or any of the classes that implement the interfaces available clientside through the service reference.

Ideally I would want the service reference to be the following:

```
public IWorkResponse DoWork(IWorkRequest request) {
    return base.Channel.DoWork(request);
}
```

I have viewed a number of answers regarding this but none seem to resolve my issue so any insight would be useful.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: I'm having trouble discerning your question.  What are you asking?

Comment: When Im creating my service reference I'm getting a return type and parameter type of "object" rather than the interfaces that are present in the actual service and looking for a way to resolve this. I'll edit my question, apologies!

Comment: How are you expecting WCF to return an interface? There is always an object that passes from server to client. You can always cast it to the interface clientside.

Comment: I was trying to make it generic so that the one service call could serve multiple request/response types. I'm quite new to using WCF so I might be approaching it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to add a comment rather than an answer but I don't have enough reputation, so here goes.

You cannot return an interface through a service operation, or pass an interface as an argument to the operation. The service and client need to be completely decoupled and not use shared interfaces. Remember that WCF clients are not always .Net applications.

If IWorkerResponse only has properties (no methods), then there is no need to use an interface at all.

Otherwise use the methods of IWorkResponse as operation contract

> ```
> [ServiceContract]
> public interface IWorkResponseService
> {
>     [OperationContract]
>     SomeResponseObject DoWork(SomeRequestObject request);
> }
> ```

It may still be possible to do what Maarten suggested in his comment.

Also see the answer to this [How do I return a reference to an interface from a WCF contract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122528/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-an-interface-from-a-wcf-contract?rq=1)

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense. As I said I'm new to WCF and the whole Service-oriented programming. I need to get my head out of OO mode! Thanks for the explanation.